# Multiple LDAP Connections With Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to modify an existing rails application that uses devise to check against an LDAP connection.  I need to check against multiple different LDAP connections.  Basically my user base is split between 2 or 3 different active directories and I'd like to be able to supply an array of connection information objects and have it run through the connections until it gets a response or fails.  Is this possible with devise?

Answer (score 4):

It is! Kind of. I hacked together a solution recently, not sure if it will be much help to you now.

First, you need to use [devise_ldap_authenticatable](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable). Once you have this installed, you can make some updates to the initialize method in the connection.rb file in this gem to accept either one configuration or many.

```
def initialize(params = {})
    ldap_configs = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(::Devise.ldap_config || "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml")).result)[Rails.env]
    ldap_configs = ldap_configs.is_a?(Hash) ? [ldap_configs] : ldap_configs
```

The next part is up to you. Due to my constraints (usernames existing in both directories), I forced a user to enter a valid domain before looping through the connections. You might not have this constraint. In either case, just loop through the configs. Once you bind successfully, break the loop. The config values will be stored in the @ldap variable that is initialized here -

```
ldap_configs.each do |ldap_config|
    #Maybe not needed if you don't have usernames in each directory. @domain is a user-entered value      
    if @domain == ldap_config["domain"]
       #This should all stay the same, until you check the bindings

          if @ldap.bind
            #If it binds, break the loop. the values in @ldap will be stored
            break
          else
           #keep looping
          end
    end
end
```

Next, make sure the ldap.yml file that devise_ldap_authenticatable generated is configured with all of your connections, including the domain, if needed -

```
## Environment

development:
 - 
  host: "localhost1.com"
  port: "389"
  attribute: uid
  base: dc=my-domain,dc=com
  admin_user: cn=admin,dc=my-domain,dc=com
  admin_password: admin_password
  ssl: false
  domain: "FIRST"
 - 
  host: "localhost2.com"
  port: "389"
  attribute: uid
  base: dc=my-domain,dc=com
  admin_user: cn=admin,dc=my-domain,dc=com
  admin_password: admin_password
  ssl: false
  domain: "SECOND"
```

Comment: is it possible to simplify this solution if I have one host (running global catalog) and multiple base configs for multiple domains?

Answer (score 1):

I built on Steve's answer with the following that seems to work well. The benefit with this is that it wraps the original code and adds functionality to it. You can keep the `ldap.yml` file the same and add a `hosts` key with an array of hosts to the YAML to exercise this.

Note that I rescue the connection error in the loop. It will still throw when it attempts, again, to make the connection that the library would already try to make.

```rb
module Devise
  module LDAP
    module ConnectionExtensions
      def initialize(params = {})
        super
        ldap_config = YAML.load(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"))[Rails.env]
        ldap_config["hosts"]&.each do |host|
          begin
            @ldap.host = host
            break if @ldap.bind
          rescue Net::LDAP::Error => e
            DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send(e)
            next
          end
        end
      end
    end

    class Connection
      prepend ConnectionExtensions
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the sample YAML file:

```
development:
  host: localhost1.com
  hosts:
    - localhost1.com
    - localhost2.com
  port: 389
  attribute: uid
  base: dc=my-domain,dc=com
  admin_user: cn=admin,dc=my-domain,dc=com
  admin_password: admin_password
  ssl: false
```

Comment: @JeffreyMCastro that's a good question that I should have specified. The module is an initializer. I called mine `config/initializers/devise_ldap.rb`

Comment: thank you :) I ended up adding mine inside the `lib/` folder, which may be a bit similar with putting it in initializer.